# Alert is undefined and 'findUser' variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I'm trying to have a JavaScript function return the username of a given user id based into my function. I'm experiencing something very strange tonight - my ReactJS.NET scripts crash, mysteriously only on this particular function (although I can put Javascript alerts in many other parts of my React script, but not all without throwing the same error).

At first, I thought it could've been a binding issue - last time, when I tried binding a similar function in another JSX script, I found this happened because when I declared the function in the constructor of the parent React component with the name of the function slightly mispelled, it was happening all over the place.

Now I can't figure out anything close to what's truly happening with this problem. Here's the function that crashes in particular, either when I try to read the value passed in, or try to call a Javascript alert inside:

```
getUsername(UserId) {
        if (!UserId) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            var stringCheck = String(Object.values(UserId));
            if (this.usersCollection.data.find(item => item.userId === stringCheck)) {
                var idx = this.usersCollection.data.findIndex(item => String(item.userId) == stringCheck);
                return this.usersCollection.data[idx].userName;
            }
            else {
                return "Nobody...";
            }
        }
    }
```

I seem to be binding it properly in the constructor of the parent component, so I'm not sure what's happening:

```
class Queue extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: this.props.initialData, closedData: this.props.closedData, selectedData: this.props.initialData };
        this.handleTicketSubmit = this.handleTicketSubmit.bind(this);
        this.toJavaScriptDate = this.toJavaScriptDate.bind(this);
        this.userState = { data: this.props.userData };
        this.usersCollection = { data: this.props.userDB };
        this.getUsername = this.getUsername.bind(this);
        this.serverMsg = { data: this.props.serverMsg };
        this.srvMsgRst = { data: this.props.srvMsgRst };
        this.showAllTickets = this.showAllTickets.bind(this);
        this.showMyTickets = this.showMyTickets.bind(this);
        this.checkServerMessage = this.checkServerMessage.bind(this);
    }
```

Here's the render function from which the getUsername function is being passed to my TicketList component:

```
render() {
        var anyClosedItems = this.state.closedData;
        return (
            <div className="queue">
                <button class="btn btn-info active" id="allTix" onClick={this.showAllTickets}>All Tasks</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="myTix" onClick={this.showMyTickets}>My Tasks</button>
                <h1>Affirm Queue</h1>



                <TicketList data={this.state.selectedData} getTicket={this.props.navUrl} renderDate={this.toJavaScriptDate} checkUser={this.getUsername} />
                <div id="noTixNotice" style={{display: 'none'}}><h3>There are no open tasks.</h3></div>
                <hr/>
                <h1>Closed Items</h1>
                {anyClosedItems.length == 0 ? <div><h3>There are currently no closed items today.</h3></div> : <TicketList data={this.state.closedData} getTicket={this.props.navUrl} renderDate={this.toJavaScriptDate} checkUser={this.getUsername} />}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Finally, here's the ticketList component itself:

```
class TicketList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const ticketNodes = this.props.data.map(ticket => (
            <TicketRow key={ticket.id} ticketLoad={this.props.getTicket+"/"+ticket.id}>

                <td>{ticket.summary}</td> <td> {ticket.description}</td><td>{this.props.renderDate({ value: ticket.currentApptTime })}</td><td>{this.props.checkUser({ UserId: ticket.userOwnerId })}</td>

            </TicketRow>
        ));
        const ticketRaw = this.props.data.map(ticket => (
            <tr>
                <td>{ticket.summary}</td><td>{ticket.description}</td><td>{this.props.renderDate({ value: ticket.currentApptTime })}</td><td>{ticket.userOwnerId}</td>
                </tr>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="ticketList">

                <table id="affirmTable" className="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Summary</th><th>Description</th><th>Appt Time</th><th>Owner</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {ticketNodes}
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I still think it's probably a problem with the JavaScript function for some weird reason, because as soon as I comment everything inside of getUsername, it's fine, but when I try to load the page with ANY code (JavaScript alert for instance), the page will crash with the "undefined" message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

Can someone let me know what could be going on here? I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: The error means that `this.usersCollection.data` is `undefined`, Have you checked if you should actually have anything there?

Comment: I think when you are calling the function 'getUsername' function in <TicketList> tag, then 'this' is referring to the TicketList component and not the 'Queue' class.

Comment: @Rahul you think that's what could be happening? The only thing is that I THINK I called similar code in a sister JSX script, so that wouldn't make sense to me, at least off the bat. I wouldn't rule it out though.

Comment: @VLAZ that is totally what did it. Up to you if you want to post your answer or you want me to post what I missed. Gotta love it when this happens to you when you copy pasta!